# can a scroll view be on half the screen (ie widh is split in 2)

Tags: android

I have a layout with a picture of a card on the right hand side.  The left hand side has a text view, then a scroll view for a text view.  The scroll view does not scroll.  Is this because a scroll view must be the whole width of the screen, cannot be split in 2?

Comment: a ScrollView does not need to be the full width of the screen. Post your code and perhaps an image of your layout if you can and we can try to help you get it working.

Comment: @Tedpottel : Do you have a `ScrollView` with a `TextView` purely to allow scrolling of the text? If so, why not simply have a scrolling `TextView`?